# Correct usage of socketcan_interface - hex2dec

Tags: ros, ros-canopen, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently started using the `socketCAN_interface` component of `ros_canopen` to get data from a Kuebler encoder.
My code is relatively straight forward, I receive messages on a particular CAN-ID using the following:

```
    can::CommInterface::FrameListener::Ptr one_frame = driver.createMsgListener(can::MsgHeader(0x101), handleFrame101);
```

Which calls the following method, writing data to a float which is a global variable:

```
void handleFrame101(const can::Frame &f){
        // handle specific frame
        std::string frame = can::tostring(f, true); //Break frame into string to extract data
        std::string data = frame.substr(frame.find("#")+1);
        //Check if data matches expected data length from frame, length/2 as dlc is hex (2 bytes per char)
        if( (data.length()/2) == int(f.dlc) ){
            uint64_t output;
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << std::hex << data;
            ss >> output;
            extension = output;
        }else{
            extension = 0;
        }
    }
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this, it seems ridiculous to decode the hex myself when [there's an inbuilt function in `socketcan_interface`](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/socketcan_interface/html/namespacecan.html#a3e30907207d610d9cea305270d0fbed7) to do so. However, I was never able to get it to take `f.data` and compile successfully. Is it an internal only function? I'm not very familiar with C++ so the documentation wasn't clear.

I'm running ubuntu 14.04 and Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258758/correct-usage-of-socketcan_interface---hex2dec/) by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can probably just use `Frame::data` directly rather that converting to a printable text string representation, it's an array of 8-bit bytes.  Find documentation for `boost::array` to find out how to get the data out. (e.g. I think `boost::array::data()` is just a pointer to the internal storage which is a C array, which can be statically recast to other data types such as uint64_t if you are sure it has at least 8 bytes.)     Or you can iterate over the data array and assemble your 64-bit number.

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2017-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mathias Lüdtke](https://answers.ros.org/users/4094/mathias-l%C3%BCdtke/) on 2017-04-08**:
Exactly! `Frame::data` can be used like regular arrays, e.g. `f.data[i]`

`boost:array` is used to get proper bounds checking.

**Comment by [rmck](https://answers.ros.org/users/29761/rmck/) on 2017-04-09**:
So if I want to translate the hex array to a float or uint I should just iterate over it and recast it?